# Use the same colorbar for each heatmap in a subplot

Tags: matlab, heatmap, colorbar

I use the following code in Matlab to create a figure consisting of 3 subplots. Each subplot is a heatmap. Normally, all the values displayed with the heatmap are in the range from 1 to 6. The problem is that sometimes, data for one of the subplots does not contain all the values. This results in different colorbars for the subplots.

```
clf
set(gcf, 'Color', 'None');
set(gca, 'Color', 'None');
set(gca, 'LooseInset', get(gca, 'TightInset'));

subplot(3,1,1);
heatmap(values1, [], [], [], 'ColorMap', @cool, 'NaNColor', [0 0 0], 'ColorBar', true);

subplot(3,1,2);
heatmap(values2, [], [], [], 'ColorMap', @cool, 'NaNColor', [0 0 0], 'ColorBar', true);

subplot(3,1,3);
heatmap(values3, [], [], [], 'ColorMap', @cool, 'NaNColor', [0 0 0], 'ColorBar', true);

fname = 'path';
saveas(gca, fullfile(fname, filename), 'png');
```

[image]

How can I use the same colobars for all 3 subplots?

Comment: Are [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/91493-how-do-i-create-a-colorbar-for-my-subplots-and-associate-the-colorbar-with-the-figure-rather-than-ea) question/answer what you want to achieve? Basically create one big colorbar, put it somewhere and alter the position of each subplots accordingly.

Comment: just set the caxis to the same values for all three plots: `caxis([1 3])`

Answer (score 2):

Except for the fantastic link on the other answer, I would like to give you some two ways to modify the colorbar. The range of the colorbar is set in the axes.

```
function test()
[xx,yy,zz]=peaks();

h_surf = surf(xx,yy,zz);
h_cbar = colorbar();
h_axes = get(h_surf,'Parent');

pause(2);
set(h_axes,'CLim',[0,8]);
pause(2);
set(h_cbar,'Limits',[4,8]);
```

Setting the property `CLim` like this is the same as using the function `caxis`. You can also change the limits on the colorbar to show a special range of the colorbar. These two alternatives should be required and sufficient to customize the range of the colorbar.

I also wish to give you a warning. Do not use the functions `gcf` and `gca`. These returns the current figure which might not be the one you think is the current. Human interaction (and maybe other things) can change the current figure (eg by clicking on it). This means that even if the code looks great, the output might not be the expected output. This problem seems to have grown worse after 2014b due to some changes in how the graphics is handled. However, the function `gca` tends to cause much less problems than `gca` since it is naturally much more complicated to interactively change the current axes on a figure, than the current figure itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can define colorbar options in this way: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colorbar.html?searchHighlight=colorbar%20plot

by the way you can go different ways: 
1. if you can change `values1,2,3` you can set '1' or any other minimal limit of colorbar scale.
2. use the way like in this link - you can define this limits by your hands but still will get black rectangles for empty values.